# How to join three tables and get value in grid view

Tags: mysql, yii2, cgridview

I have three tables :

1. `contacts` hasMany groups
2. `contact_groups` hasMany contacts
3. `contact_contact_groups`

columns in table **contact**

`contact_id | contact_name`

columns in table **contact_groups**

`group_id | group_name`

columns in table **contact_contact_groups**

`contact_contact_group_id | contact_id | group_id`

**MODEL**

***contacs model***

```
public function getContactContactGroups()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ContactContactGroups::className(),
                          ['contact_id' => 'contact_id']);
}
```

***contact_groups model***

```
public function getContactContactGroups()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ContactContactGroups::className(),
                          ['group_id' => 'group_id']);
}
```

***contact_contact_groups model***

```
public function getGroup()
{
  return $this->hasOne(ContactGroups::className(), ['group_id' => 'group_id']);
}

public function getContact()
{
  return $this->hasOne(Contacts::className(), ['contact_id' => 'contact_id']);
}
```

I want to display grid like this :

```
-----------------------------
Contact Name | Group Name
-----------------------------
Me           | Uncategorized
Mother       | Family
Jhon         | Business
```

**VIEW**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'filterModel' => $searchModel,
  'tableOptions' =>['class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered'],
  'columns' => [
    [
      'attribute' => 'contact_name',
      'value' => 'contact_name',
    ],
    [
      'attribute' => 'contactContactGroups.group_id',
      'value' => 'contactContactGroups.group.group_name',
      'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'group_id', ArrayHelper::map(ContactGroups::find()->where(['group_status'=>'ACTIVE'])->asArray()->all(), 'group_id', 'group_name'),['class'=>'form-control','prompt' => 'Select Group']),
    ],
  ],]); 
?>
```

**ContactsController**

```
public function actionIndex() { 
    $this->unsetThisButton(array(4,5));   
    $searchModel = new ContactsSearch(); 
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams); 
    return $this->render('index', [ 
          'searchModel' => $searchModel, 
          'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     ]); 
}
```

But it showing  `(not set)` not a group_name .

Comment: But how do you plan to show a contact with more than one group? in a single row (all groups separated by, for example, comma) or each combination of contact|group in a row?

Comment: I combine with implode for `group_id` and then I call function to get the group name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found simple stuff like this :)

***GRID (VIEW)***

```
[
        'attribute' => 'contactContactGroups.group_id',
        'value'=>function ($data) {
            $d = array();
            foreach ($data->contactContactGroups as $k=>$m)
            {
              $d[] = ContactContactGroups::get_group_name_by_id($m->group_id);
            }
            return implode($d, ', '); 
          },
        'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'group_id', ArrayHelper::map(ContactGroups::find()->where(['group_status'=>'ACTIVE'])->asArray()->all(), 'group_id', 'group_name'),['class'=>'form-control','prompt' => 'Select Group']),
      ],
```

***models/ContactContactGroups.php Model***

I create function `get_group_name_by_id($id)`

```
public static function get_group_name_by_id($id){
  $model = ContactGroups::find()->where(["group_id" => $id])->one();
  if(!empty($model)){
    return $model->group_name;
  }
  return null;
}
```

so the result is :

```
Contact   | Category
-------------------------------
Me        | Business, Family
Erick     | Business, Office
Jhon      | Office
```

Thank's @scaisEdge, you give me `some clue` ;)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is based on adding  a getter in your model eg: for contact_contact_groups model

you have a relation

```
public function getGroup()
{
  return $this->hasOne(ContactGroups::className(), ['group_id' => 'group_id']);
}
```

use a getter  for group_name

```
 public function getGroup_group_name() {
    return $this->group->group_name;
}
```

and in grid view  in the attribute

```
[
  'attribute' => 'group_group_name',
  'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'group_id', ArrayHelper::map(ContactGroups::find()->where(['group_status'=>'ACTIVE'])->asArray()->all(), 'group_id', 'group_name'),['class'=>'form-control','prompt' => 'Select Group']),
],
```

do the same for the relation and field

Comment: still give me `(not set)` value, not a group name :(

Comment: Which is the controller of the related view (gridView) ?

Comment: I don't make change anything in ContactsController, this is my controller :

```public function actionIndex()
  {
    $this->unsetThisButton(array(4,5));

    $searchModel = new ContactsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
      'searchModel' => $searchModel,
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
  }```

Comment: But you contact model you don'thave the relation with  group ...I think you need these relation in the model that is the base for dataProvider ..