# JOIN multiple table using relations in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-model

I am trying to list some data through `Kartik GridView` widget in `yii2` by using relations.
I have these tables

```
staffs

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `staffs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `department_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `designation_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `emailid` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `staffrights` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `staffstatus` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
designations

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `designations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `designname` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `designation_group_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



designation_group 


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `designation_group` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_name` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

`designations` table is related to  `designation_group` by `designations.designation_group_id` . `designations` table will have one or more values seperated by comma, of `designation_group.id` .

`designations`  table is related to staffs table by `staffs.designation_id =designations.id`.
In `Staffs` Model I have added relations like this

```
public function getDesignations() {
        return $this->hasOne( Designations::className(), ['id' => 'designation_id']);
    }
```

and is working perfect. But the relation for `designation_group` I tried like this:

```
public function getDesgroupstaffs(){
        return $this->hasOne(Designations::className() , ['id' => 'id'])
                    ->from(Designationgroup::tableName() ) ;
}
```

But it doesnt give the expected result.
How the `designation_group` table can be joined so that all the designation group associated with the staff can also be displayed ?
I want to show like, the first column of grid view will be designations, while filter of the same column should be DesignationGroup.group_name. SO if any group_name is selected , it will show data of staffs associated with that group name

Comment: use yii2 joinWidth like...  `Model::find()->joinWith(['Relation Name'])->all();` refer this link [Join With Relation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html)

Comment: The relation does not Desgroupstaffs give the designation group

Comment: this one relation is wrong `['id' => 'id']` in `getDesgroupstaffs()` function

Comment: designation_group has relation with designations. designations will have multple values of designation_group

Comment: use relation like `['id' => 'designation_group_id']`

Comment: It shows an error Database Exception – yii\db\Exception

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'staffs.designation_group_id' in 'on clause'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `staffs` LEFT JOIN `designations` ON `staffs`.`designation_id` = `designations`.`id` LEFT JOIN `departments` ON `staffs`.`department_id` = `departments`.`id` LEFT JOIN `designation_group` ON `staffs`.`designation_group_id` = `designation_group`.`id`

Comment: So this is a many-to-many relationship? Where a Designation group can have many designations, and designations can have many designation groups? Is there a reason for the csv, rather than a junction table?

Comment: designations table may  have one or many designation_group_id within a single row which will be sepeated by ',' like 1,2,3

Comment: Yeah, and i believe that's where your problem is. I think you need a custom SQL (have a look at Mysqls `find_in_set()` and `like`) or if its still possible add a junction table.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot join with comma seperated ids. Wouldn't it be an option to have a column `designation_id` in `designation_group` instead of the `designation_group_id` in `designations`?

Comment: Try hasMany in second relation.

Answer (score 2):

Well, from what I was able to extract from your question, you want to be able to get the group name for each of the staffs. The code below will help you accomplish that task.

Inside the staff model, create a relationship as stated below or you can use an existing one which I am sure Yii would have automatically generated it for you

**STAFF model**

```
public function getDesignation()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Designation::className(),['designation_id'=>'id]);
}
```

Inside the designation model,create another relation that links the degination model with the designationGroup model, which would have been automatically created as well

**Designation MOdel**

```
public function getDesignationGroup()
{
   return $this->hasOne(DesignationGroup::className(),['id'=>'designation_group_id]);
}
```

Finally, on your gridview, you can use the code below to get the group name

```
$model->destination->designationGroup->group_name
```

I hope this solves your problem. Though i have used it couple of times.

Comment: The filter in grid view does not show correct data. designation_group_id are a set of comma separated values. the first column of grid view will be designations, while filter of the same column should be DesignationGroup.group_name

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, it's looks like my problem a few days ago. [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499252/how-to-join-three-tables-and-get-value-in-grid-view/35520198#35520198)

I have three tables (contact, contact_groups and contact_contact_groups) which has many-to-many relation. It means one contact has many groups, and one group has many contacts. So I create one table to make relations One-to-Many.

but the result will like this :

```
contact | contact groups
-------------------------
contact #1 | business1, business2, family
contact #2 | family
contact #3 | student, partner
```

Answer (score 0):

**staff model**

> use `->with(['designationgroup'])`

```
public function getDesignation()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Designation::className(),['designation_id'=>'id])->with(['designationgroup']);
}
```

**designation model**

```
public function getDesignationgroup()
{
   return $this->hasOne(DesignationGroup::className(),['id'=>'designation_group_id]);
}
```

On `GridView` , render the value as

```
$model->destination->designationgroup->group_name
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you to remove the column `designation_group_id` from designation table, because it contains multiples comma separated values. Create one more table named designation_group_assigned, which will have the following columns: `Id`, `designation_id`, `designation_group_id`

In this table, we can insert multiple rows if one designation belongs to multiple groups.

And then you can use the yii relationships for one to many records.